# How to pass argument without navigating to the route in flutter

Tags: flutter, routes, navigation

I Have a loading screen when the data is loaded I navigate to the dashboard route which contain App bar and BottomNavigationBar which will display different routes.
But I also need the data that was loaded in the the loading routes to be sent to the home route without navigate to it
this is the loading route:

```
void routingToHomePage() async {
List dataList = [];
final response = await http.get(
    Uri.parse('http://192.168.1.9/Backend/Back.php'));
print("StatusCode== ${response.statusCode}");
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  setState(() {
    dataList =
        json.decode(response.body);
    print("this is the data from the loading screen${dataList}");
    Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/dash'); //this is the dashboard route
    Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/home', arguments: { //Here I want to send only the arguments without navigating to the route
      'dataList': dataList,

    });
  });
```

Comment: Just for clarification, I assume you mean route instead of root?

Comment: do you know about callback functions? A function of parent getting executed in child

Comment: why would you need the data when you are not on the page?

Comment: @MindStudio because I will display the page inside the dashboard screen

Comment: I'm new in flutter @AsimJawad

Comment: well, you create a function in one class in which you can change the values of the variables and then you pass the same function as a reference or variable to the child or other class.

Comment: Thanks @AsimJawad can you give me an example?

Comment: yeah, sure let me create one